# How to add a list within a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, list

Ive got a method in a WCF service that returns a list of questions, along with these questions are some options(Answers) which can be selected.

The options are then added to a RadioButtonList on the client apps so that the client may make the appropriate selection for a specific question.

My question is how would i add a List within the List that i am returning to the client app.

I would like to return a list of options for a specific question.

This is what i have so far,

```
public class ct_auditResults
{
    private int AuditResultsID { get; set; }
    private int QuestionID { get; set; }
    private string Question { get; set; }
    private string QuestionValue { get; set; }
    private int QuestionTypeID { get; set; }
    private bool IsOptional { get; set; }
    private bool AllowComments { get; set; }
    private bool AllowActions { get; set; }
    private List<QuestionOptionText> OptionText { get; set; }

    public int auditResultsID
    {
        get { return AuditResultsID; }
        set { AuditResultsID = value; }
    }

    public int questionID
    {
        get { return QuestionID; }
        set { QuestionID = value; }
    }

    public string question
    {
        get { return Question; }
        set { Question = value; }
    }

    public string questionValue
    {
        get { return QuestionValue; }
        set { QuestionValue = value; }
    }

    public int questionTypeID
    {
        get { return QuestionTypeID; }
        set { QuestionTypeID = value; }
    }

    public bool isOptional
    {
        get { return IsOptional; }
        set { IsOptional = value; }
    }

    public bool allowComments
    {
        get { return AllowComments; }
        set { AllowComments = value; }
    }

    public bool allowActions
    {
        get { return AllowActions; }
        set { AllowActions = value; }
    }

    public List<QuestionOptionText> optionText
    {
        get { return OptionText; }
        set { OptionText = value; }
    }


    public class QuestionOptionText
    {
        private string QuestionText { get; set; }

        public string questionText
        {
            get { return QuestionText; }
            set { QuestionText = value; }
        }
    }
}

class AuditResultsClass : IAuditResults
{
    CTDBDataContext db = new CTDBDataContext();

    public List<ct_auditResults> getQuestionsForSubSectionAudit(long _SiteAuditID, long _SubSectionID)
    {
        List<ct_auditResults> QuestionList = (from ar in db.AuditResults
                                                join q in db.Questions on ar.QuestionID equals q.QuestionID
                                                join qt in db.QuestionTypes on q.QuestionTypeID equals qt.QuestionTypeID
                                                join opt in db.Options on q.QuestionID equals opt.QuestionID
                                                where ar.SiteAuditID == _SiteAuditID &&
                                                    ar.SubSectionID == _SubSectionID
                                                select new ct_auditResults
                                                {
                                                    auditResultsID = ar.SiteAuditID,
                                                    questionID = ar.QuestionID,
                                                    questionValue = ar.QuestionValue,
                                                    questionTypeID = q.QuestionTypeID,
                                                    question = q.Question1,
                                                    isOptional = q.IsOptional,
                                                    allowComments = q.AlowComments,
                                                    allowActions = q.AllowActions,
                                                    // I would like to return the option list List<QuestionOptionText> OptionText
                                                }).ToList();
        return QuestionList;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to either make a `questionWithAnswers` class and then serialize and send that? Or you pack a question as a set of 5 "options", the first actually being the question, the second being the correct answer, shuffle on client-side and then pack that as a `List<List<string>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the select with:

```
select new ct_auditResults
{
  ....
  optionText = some_query.ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the table is called `QuestionOptionTexts`. Then you can do this:

```
question = q.Question1,
isOptional = q.IsOptional,
allowComments = q.AlowComments,
allowActions = q.AllowActions,
OptionText = db.QuestionOptionTexts
             .Where(w=>w.QuestionID==q.QuestionID)
             .Select(s=>new QuestionOptionText(){questionText=s.QuestionText})
             .ToList()
}).ToList();
```